# MSN Protocol 11 implementation

Tags: msn

I am working on a MSNP 11 implementation and currently having some issues with Challenge response generation.

Does some one has a good knowledge about the algorithm used to generate the Challenge response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little late but I was searching through SO for MSN related posts and this showed up. 
You can find an explanation of the challengestring in MSNP11 and some examples [here](http://msnpiki.msnfanatic.com/index.php/MSNP11%3aChallenges).

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Actually this site explains the MSN Protocol best and I managed to implement the CHallenge Algorithm response using the information in there.